# Smack api and Java

Tags: java, chat, xmpp, tapestry, smack

I am using Tapestry 5, Smack api 3.1.0.

I have established a connection and am able to communicate with a user through the xmpp server but the replies i get are sent to the standard output as they come in:

```
Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("blah@jabber.org", new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message.getBody());                   // this works

        showonbrowser = message.getBody();                                                   
        System.out.println(showonbrowser) // this prints nothing
    }
};
```

I am looking to get the replies to my html file so i can read them on the web instead of the console.  However, when i try to set message.getBody() to showonbrowser (a property on the page) i see no result.  Does anyone know how I get around this?

Regards,

Kace

Answer (score 2):

Smack is multi-threading and it has a nasty habit of eating up exceptions that are thrown (silently.) Most likely you are not using a thread-safe GUI and its throwing an exception that you never get.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `processMessage` method is being called *after* the page is rendered.

You are creating a MessageListener instance (through an anonymous class), so you don't know when the processMessage method will be called. I think you would have to do something with AJAX to do partial updates on the page, polling the server and getting any new messages to show them on the page.